# MS SQL datetime representation in go-gorm

Tags: sql-server, database, go, go-gorm

Title says it all. I'm using gorm (golang orm) to connect to a MS SQL db.

time.Time gets me datetime2 which is a different dataType. Any suggestions?

**Structure:**

```
type (
    ACDepartements struct {
        DEPTID              int         `gorm:"column:DEPTID;primary_key;not null;"`
        DEPTNAME            string      `gorm:"column:DEPTNAME;size:30;"`
        SUPDEPTID           int         `gorm:"column:SUPDEPTID;not null;"`
        InheritParentSch    int16       `gorm:"column:InheritParentSch;size:5;"`
        InheritDeptSch      int16       `gorm:"column:InheritDeptSch;"`
        InheritDeptSchClass int16       `gorm:"column:InheritDeptSchClass;"`
        AutoSchPlan         int16       `gorm:"column:AutoSchPlan;"`
        InLate              int16       `gorm:"column:InLate;"`
        OutEarly            int16       `gorm:"column:OutEarly;"`
        InheritDeptRule     int16       `gorm:"column:InheritDeptRule;"`
        MinAutoSchInterval  int         `gorm:"column:MinAutoSchInterval;"`
        RegisterOT          int16       `gorm:"column:RegisterOT;"`
        DefaultSchId        int         `gorm:"column:DefaultSchId;not null;"`
        ATT                 int16       `gorm:"column:ATT;"`
        Holiday             int16       `gorm:"column:Holiday;"`
        OverTime            int16       `gorm:"column:OverTime;"`
        ChangeOperator      string      `gorm:"size:50;"`
        ChangeTime          time.Time
        CreateOperator      string      `gorm:"size:50;"`
        CreateTime          time.Time
        DeleteOperator      string      `gorm:"size:50;"`
        DeleteTime          time.Time
        Status              int     
        Code                string      `gorm:"size:50;"`
        Type                string      `gorm:"size:50;"`
        Invalidate          time.Time
    }
)
```

**Connection:**

```
func buildAcDB() *gorm.DB {
    connectionString  := os.Getenv("MS_SQL")

    acDB, err := gorm.Open("mssql", connectionString)

    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to create connection pool. Error: " + err.Error())
    }
    gorm.DefaultCallback.Create().Remove("mssql:set_identity_insert")

    return acDB
}
```

**Server:**

```
func Start(db *gorm.DB, acDB *gorm.DB) {

Other stuff......

defer acDB.Close()

acDB.AutoMigrate(microlab.ACDepartements{})

}
```

**Problem:**

If I check the data structure of my created table, time variables have datetime2 instead of datetime as I want. Also int16 are int instead of smallint but I guess that doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Could you provide code? This `time.Time gets me datetime2 which is a different dataType` is not clear. Thanks!

Comment: Code updated. Also, if I try to create an entry I get:
The conversion of a datetimeoffset data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: What about using the type tag in the gorm tag of the field? `Email   string  'gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index"'` (http://doc.gorm.io/models.html) Also check this issue: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/18

Comment: You mean like: DeleteTime time.Time `gorm:"type:datetime(23);"`
It doesnt work. Same issue

Comment: Without the "(23)" I meant. That must indicate the length of the field, which iirc is not needed for datetime fields

Comment: It does work but I still get the error when I try to save data to the table because is type is different.
Basically I need to use something different than time.Time